# Can I install a module once, then send the .py somewhere else and have it still work?

Tags: python, module

Just wondering, if I installed a module for python, (for example, pygame) and sent the .py to my school account, would I still need to send the module in the folder with it or would it just store the module within the .py?

Comment: It would simply be a **NO!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to install the same module on the destination computer for it to work.  Your .py file is plain text, nothing more than what it looks like; it doesn't have any special way to store dependencies.

Comment: Hey Andrew. I have a kinda weird favour to ask, but can you please delete your answer? It was really helpful and all, but the actual question is taking down my rep to the point where I cant ask questions any more, and I cant delete it if there is an answer attached. I've flagged for a mod, but to no avail. You don't have to, but I'd really appreciate it. -Thanks :)

Comment: @user3092506 Try to ask a new question now and see if you're still blocked.

Comment: @user3092506 deleted questions are still counted for the purposes of a ban, so upvotes (for instance by submitting answers that are upvoted) are the only way to reverse it.